# Swift - TableView Cells requires double-taps in non-debug mode

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a tableview with cells which trigger a segue when selected, taking me to the next view. Everything happens perfectly if I put break-points in the code.

TableView is not the first View in the app. It's is loaded via a segue from the Main Screen of the app via an on-screen button, which surprisingly doesn't exhibit this behaviour(single click works fine first time itself).

However, I need to click a cell "twice"(time difference between the clicks doesnt matter) to select it first time when there are no break-points. Thereon, single clicks are fine. Testing this on my Xcode iPhone simulator.

My Code -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Keep track of the Holding selected
    self.selectedHolding = self.portfolio.holdings[indexPath.row]

    // Trigger the segue to the detail view
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHoldingTransactionsSegue", sender: self)
    }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if let actualIdentifier = segue.identifier {
        if actualIdentifier == "toHoldingTransactionsSegue" {
        let holdingTransactionsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as HoldingTransactionsViewController
        holdingTransactionsViewController.holding = self.selectedHolding
        holdingTransactionsViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'twice' ? In quick succession, or it just doesn't respond the first time? How is the segue triggered? Should your code.

Comment: Not in quick succession, it just doesn't respond the first time. Even if I wait a few seconds for clicking it second time, it works.

Comment: I have updated my question with code for triggering the segue.

Comment: Is it called both times? In your storyboard do you have the segue connected to the cell or to the view controller?

Comment: It is called both the times. The segue is connected to the cell.

Comment: You should try connecting the segue to the view controller instead.

Comment: added as answer below

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the segue to the view controller instead of to the cell. When you connect the segue to the cell directly it bypasses / interferes with didSelectCellAtIndexPath